# Find exact match with find method

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this block of code, i unzip a file to search for one specific file called node.txt but if i have more files named as node.txt.old or node.txt.new it shows up on the search.

So, in short, how could i limit the `loop_package.find("node.txt")` to only match the exact file?

```
import zipfile
import re

ziproot = zipfile.ZipFile('c:\\zips\somezip.zip')
node_list = []
for loop_package in ziproot.namelist():
    if loop_package.find("node.txt"):
        for line in ziproot.read(loop_package).split("\n"):
            if line.find("doc-node") >= 0:
                node_dict = dict()
                for iline in ziproot.read(loop_package).split("\n"):
                    if iline.find("node_nsName") >= 0:
                        mt = re.search(r'(.*>)(.*?)(<.*)', iline, re.M | re.I)
                        node_dict['filePath'] = loop_package
                        node_dict['nodeCon'] = mt.group(2)
                        node_list.append(node_dict)
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                pass
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: All of those `else: pass`'s do nothing.  You can remove them entirely without affecting the operation of the script.

Comment: @iCodez I know, but i think it's more organized to keep the if's closed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `endswith` instead of `find`.

```
for loop_package in ziproot.namelist():
    if loop_package.endswith("node.txt"):
```

Since loop_package is an entire file path, we are interested in the end of such a string, the file name.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. There's no reason to iterate through the list, it's cleaner to just check if the string is in the list (sure it iterates through the list anyway..)

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell Each element of `ziproot.namelist()` contains the full path to the file, like `'dir1/dir2/node.txt'`. Checking `if 'node.txt' in ziproot.namelist()` won't catch that. Besides, he has further processing to do on that item and multiple could exist at different paths.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell There is a reason to iterate through the list.since i need to check all lines for each file.

Comment: @Thales I suppose it's semantics at that point, but you can certainly also do this: if "node.txt" in ziproot.namelist() \ ziproot.read("node.txt").split("\n"):

Or, don't even check. Just wrap it in a try/except block instead which raises an exception if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell Thanks for the suggestion, but this block of code work as intende. And like the old wizard says: Some people prefer squares and others prefer circles. and in this case, circle works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a string in a list of strings. Python makes this pretty easy!

You don't want to use the find() method. You want to search ziproot.namelist() as such:

```
if "node.txt" in ziproot.namelist():
```